# Issues installing Server 2008 R2 on Dell Poweredge R510

Tags: windows, dell

I've got two newly delivered R510's and am trying to install Server 2008 R2 obtained from Microsoft BizSpark.

I've burnt the ISO to a 16GB USB stick but although the install goes ahead when it comes to building the desktop for the first time (after setting the Admin password) it stalls on the blue desktop background with no icons and no taskbar.

I've left it running on that screen for hours with now change.

I've killed the partition a good 2 or 3 times, rebuilt it and reinstalled but nothing helps.

I've considered burning the ISO to DVD but haven't got that far just yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe there is a corrupt usb drive, hard drive, or os.

Comment: Yup, I'm certainly considering those options. For now, I think it's the USB stick - possibly something to do with the fact that it is 16GB and not 4, or something along those lines. I'm currently burning the ISO to 2 DVD's and also to a 4GB USB stick, if none of these work then I think I'm going to loose my sense of humour.

Comment: Just a quick update to say we've sorted this issue.

It turns out that Dell know they have a problem with R510's were the customer has specified extra NICs - specifically were the customer has specified dual or quad port NICs.

If you remove the NICs from the machine then Windows Server 2008 R2 installs without an issue!

(t'would be nice if the Dell Support techies had this on their list of things to check FIRST, before sending their customers on wild goose chases installing using UEFI, USB sticks and other stuff like that!)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update to say we've sorted this issue.

It turns out that Dell know they have a problem with R510's were the customer has specified extra NICs - specifically were the customer has specified dual or quad port NICs.

If you remove the NICs from the machine then Windows Server 2008 R2 installs without an issue!

(t'would be nice though if the Dell Support techies had this on their list of things to check FIRST, before sending their customers on wild goose chases installing using UEFI, USB sticks and other stuff like that! We wasted 4 days on this issue)